Why does a toolbar from one Tabbar view show up in another Tabbar view
I have a rootview that wraps a tabbarview in a navigationStack:
NavigationStack {
    TabbarView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
}

Then in TabbarView I have a tabView that has each one of its items wrapped in a NavStack, now the problem is that I have a toolbar in ProductsView and it showing up at the top of the other views that should have no toolbar:
struct TabbarView: View {
    @Binding var showSignInView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                ProductsView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "cart")
                Text("Products")
            }

            NavigationStack {
                FavoritesView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                Text("Favourites")
            }
            
            NavigationStack {
                ProfileView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                Text("Profile")
            }
        }
    }
}

So far I have tried removing the navigation stack around each tab item and also removing the parents navStack in RootView and it didnt work, I have also tried giving the two other views an empty toolbar and that also didn't work.

You should not put a TabView in a NavigationStack. Why do you want to do that?

It was a mistake removing it and moving the location of the NavigationStack fixed the issue, check out the answer and tell me if its acceptable

So this appears to be a bug in SwiftUI and the way to fix it is first to remove the NavigationStack around your TabView and then remove the NavigationStack around your tabbar items:
TabView {
    ProductsView()
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "cart")
            Text("Products")
        }
    FavoritesView()
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
            Text("Favourites")
        }
    ProfileView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "person")
            Text("Profile")
        }
}

And then move those NavigationStacks inside the body of each view like so:
struct ProfileView: View {
    
    @State private var viewModel = ProfileViewModel()
    @Binding var showSignInView: Bool
    let PreferenceOptions: [String] = ["Sports", "Movies", "Music"]
    
    private func preferenceIsSelected(_ text: String) -> Bool {
        return viewModel.user?.preferences?.contains(text) == true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                if let user = viewModel.user {
                    Text("Userid: \(user.userId)")
                }
                if let isAnomymous = viewModel.user?.isAnonymous {
                    Text("Anonymous: \(isAnomymous)")
                }
                
                Button {
                    //toggling the premium status in firebase Auth
                    viewModel.togglePremiumStatus()
                } label: {
                    Text("User is premium: \((viewModel.user?.isPremium ?? false).description.uppercased())")
                }
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(PreferenceOptions, id: \.self) {preference in
                            Button(preference) {
                                if preferenceIsSelected(preference) {
                                    viewModel.removeUserPreference(text: preference)
                                }
                                else {
                                    viewModel.addUserPreference(text: preference)
                                }
                            }
                            .font(.headline)
                            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                            .tint(preferenceIsSelected(preference) ? .green : .red)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    Text("User preferences: \((viewModel.user?.preferences ?? []).joined (separator: ", "))")
                    
                }
                Button {
                    if viewModel.user?.favoriteMovie == nil {
                        viewModel.addFavoriteMovie()
                    }
                    else {
                        viewModel.removeFavoriteMovie()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Favorite Movie: \(viewModel.user?.favoriteMovie?.title ?? "")")
                }
                
            }
        }
        .task {
            try? await viewModel.loadCurrentUser()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Profile")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                NavigationLink {
                    SettingsView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
                }
                label:  {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                        .font(.headline)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


It is not a bug. Each TabView should have its own NavigationStack, not the other way around.

They did, I just moved the navigationStack into the body of each of the views and now it works
